# How did the culprit create the Darkasher?

Tags: plot-explanation, carnival-row

At the end of the first season of [Carnival Row](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0489974/), we find out that

> Lady Piety is the one who created the Darkasher and orchestrated all of the murders that the plot of the first season revolves around.

Like other viewers, I wondered who might be behind it all while watching the season, but one thing threw me off of the right guess. When Philo was investigating the case, he wanted proof that a Darkasher is even possible. One of the things we learned then is that his "seed" was necessary and that this is how the Darkasher would be tied to him. Also, it was made quite obvious that the seed in question is exactly what it sounds like: his sperm.

So, how did a female antagonist create a Darkasher?

There is [some discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CarnivalRow/comments/cyki2w/spoiler_question_about_the_darkasher/) about this, with guesses of her or her unknown accomplice taking out her egg or an ovary. A dead (post-menstrual) egg doesn't fit the purpose, and taking out a live one (or more) would require quite a significant surgical procedure, one which I'd expect not to escape her husband. Or, at least, she wouldn't be able to count on him not noticing.

Normally, I'd chuck away this as "unimportant trivia", which is not welcome here, but seeing as it thorougly throws the suspicion away from the real culprit, I think it's a good enough question. Is it a major plot hole, or is there a better explanation for this? A mention from the authors or some source material that I've missed?

Comment: Interesting, I haven't thought of this detail. I need to rewatch the series.